# jQuery animating left: '-125%' not working

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I have a wizard I'm trying to build and the animation just isn't working.

```
    jQuery('#btnNext').on('click', function () {
        jQuery('#page_' + currentPage).animate(
            {
                left: '-125%'
            },
            200
        );
    });
```

In my chrome debugger, the left element gets applied, but the div doesn't move at all.  my CSS looks like this:

```
.wizard 
{
    display:block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}
.wizardPage
{
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 1em; 
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    width: 796px;
}
#btnFirst, #btnPrevious{ float: left; margin-right: 0.5em;}
#btnNext, #btnFinish{float: right; margin-left: 0.5em; }
.wizard .wizardPage, #pageNavigator .navButton
{
    display: none;
}
#pageNavigator{width: 796px;}
```

and the HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="pageContainer" class="wizard">
    <div class="wizardPage" id="page_1">
        <div class="editLine">
            <label for="FirstName">
                First Name:</label>
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field First Name must be a string with a maximum length of 40."
                data-val-length-max="40" data-val-required="The First Name field is required."
                id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true">
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="editLine">
            <label for="MiddleName">
                Middle Name:</label>
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Middle Name must be a string with a maximum length of 40."
                data-val-length-max="40" data-val-required="The Middle Name field is required."
                id="MiddleName" name="MiddleName" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="MiddleName" data-valmsg-replace="true">
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="editLine">
            <label for="LastName">
                Last Name:</label>
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Last Name must be a string with a maximum length of 40."
                data-val-length-max="40" data-val-required="The Last Name field is required."
                id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="LastName" data-valmsg-replace="true">
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="editLine">
            <label for="State" title="Due to state registration requirements, we are currently accepting investors from select states.">
                State of Residence:</label>
            <select name="State" id="State">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="AK" title="Alaska">AK</option>
                <option value="AL" title="Alabama">AL</option>
                <option value="AR" title="Arkansas">AR</option>
                <option value="AZ" title="Arizona">AZ</option>
                <option value="CA" title="California">CA</option>
                <option value="CO" title="Colorado">CO</option>
                <option value="CT" title="Connecticut">CT</option>
                <option value="DC" title="District of Columbia">DC</option>
                <option value="DE" title="Delaware">DE</option>
                <option value="FL" title="Florida">FL</option>
                <option value="GA" title="Georgia">GA</option>
                <option value="HI" title="Hawaii">HI</option>
                <option value="IA" title="Iowa">IA</option>
                <option value="ID" title="Idaho">ID</option>
                <option value="IL" title="Illinois">IL</option>
                <option value="IN" title="Indiana">IN</option>
                <option value="KS" title="Kansas">KS</option>
                <option value="KY" title="Kentucky">KY</option>
                <option value="LA" title="Louisiana">LA</option>
                <option value="MA" title="Massachusetts">MA</option>
                <option value="MD" title="Maryland">MD</option>
                <option value="ME" title="Maine">ME</option>
                <option value="MI" title="Michigan">MI</option>
                <option value="MN" title="Minnesota">MN</option>
                <option value="MO" title="Missouri">MO</option>
                <option value="MS" title="Mississippi">MS</option>
                <option value="MT" title="Montana">MT</option>
                <option value="NC" title="North Carolina">NC</option>
                <option value="ND" title="North Dakota">ND</option>
                <option value="NE" title="Nebraska">NE</option>
                <option value="NH" title="New Hampshire">NH</option>
                <option value="NJ" title="New Jersey">NJ</option>
                <option value="NM" title="New Mexico">NM</option>
                <option value="NV" title="Nevada">NV</option>
                <option value="NY" title="New York">NY</option>
                <option value="OH" title="Ohio">OH</option>
                <option value="OK" title="Oklahoma">OK</option>
                <option value="OR" title="Oregon">OR</option>
                <option value="PA" title="Pennsylvania">PA</option>
                <option value="RI" title="Rhode Island">RI</option>
                <option value="SC" title="South Carolina">SC</option>
                <option value="SD" title="South Dakota">SD</option>
                <option value="TN" title="Tennessee">TN</option>
                <option value="TX" title="Texas">TX</option>
                <option value="UT" title="Utah">UT</option>
                <option value="VA" title="Virginia">VA</option>
                <option value="VT" title="Vermont">VT</option>
                <option value="WA" title="Washington">WA</option>
                <option value="WI" title="Wisconsin">WI</option>
                <option value="WV" title="West Virginia">WV</option>
                <option value="WY" title="Wyoming">WY</option>
            </select>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="State" data-valmsg-replace="true">
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="editLine">
            <label for="BirthDate" title="You must be at least 18 years old to participate in Charlesfund.com.">
                Birth Date:</label>
            <input class="datePicker" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Birth Date field is required."
                id="BirthDate" name="BirthDate" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="BirthDate" data-valmsg-replace="true">
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wizardPage" id="page_2">
        Page 2<br />
        blah bla blah
    </div>
    <div id="pageNavigator">
        <a class="navButton" id="btnFirst">&lt;&lt; First</a> <a class="navButton" id="btnPrevious">
            &lt; Previous</a> <a class="navButton" id="btnFinish">Last &gt;&gt;</a> <a class="navButton"
                id="btnNext">Next &gt;</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?  I should mention that the divs are made visible in the `ready()` function.

Comment: When you specify `125%`, what do you mean?  `125%` of what?

Comment: Not an appropriate question title. It should summarize your question.

Comment: Is the object that you're trying to animate with the `left` value set to `position: absolute`?  If not, the `top`, `bottom`, `right` and `left` won't do anything.

Comment: are you trying do a slider?? and can we have a preview i can help you better that way

Comment: I'm trying to scroll the div off the page, so I can scroll another div in from the right.

Comment: I would suggest instead of `125%` to do it in pixels. Just take the original value and multiply by 1.25 in JS and it would be the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change the position of the object to absolute you can try to play with margin-left instead.

```
$('body').on('click','#btnNext', function () {
    $('#page_1').animate(
        {
             'margin-left': '-125%'
        },
        200
    );
});​
```